# How to find the name of a media button on a Bluetooth headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth headset which has a special button different from the normal media buttons, and I am trying to find how is that button called in order to call a separate application when this button is pressed. I have tried to listen for the Bluetooth headset intents but no luck for the moment.
 If you guys can give me any hints or point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You headset is probably broadcasting a [Vendor Specific Headset Event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html#ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT).

This is the standard intent to broadcast a "special" action from Bluetooth. You can register a listener on this intent on the `BluetoothHeadset` class.